# PowerShell select one of three options

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Currently I have a "script" where the users enters a username, the script then sets a specific out of office message on the users exchange account for 1 month.

I would like to add a feature where either via a startup flag or a popup menu they user can pick from three different options (Office A, Office B and Office C). Depending on the one they pick a different message is put as Out-of-office.

```
    #### Connect to exchange ####
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://sto-ms-03/PowerShell -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session 
#### User Info ###
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your username'
$StartDate = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-2) -f yyyy/MM/dd
$EndDate = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddMonths(+1) -f yyyy/MM/dd
$Dummymessage1 = "This is dummy number 1"


Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity "DOMAIN\$Username" -StartTime "$StartDate" -EndTime "$EndDate" -ExternalMessage "$Dummymessage1" -InternalMessage "$Dummymessage1"
```

So if possible I would like to add a popup button that allows the choise of A, B or C. A, B and C would be tied to 3 different variables that just replace `$Dummymessage`

Edit: Ended up using the following as the solution:

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet("A", "B", "C")]
    [string]$Office
)
if($Office -eq 'A') {$Message = "Dummy 1"}
if($Office -eq 'B') {$Message = "Dummy 2"}
if($Office -eq 'C') {$Message = "Dummy 3"}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a `Param` section to the first line of your script:

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet("Office A", "Office B", "Office C")]
    [string]$Office
)
```

The user who invokes your script now have to pass either `Office A`, `Office B` or `Office C` and also gets a selection within the console:

[image]

I would also allow the user to pass the Credential and Username to the script (just add it to the `Param` block).

Comment: This defently looks like what I am looking for, I'll give it a try and see if i can figure out how to implement it. Otherwise i'll return back.

Comment: You probably want to use that parameter in a format string like `"The user {0} is out of {1}" -f $Username, $Office`. This will result in something like `The user Michael is out of Office A`.

Comment: Issue is the offices are in three diffrent countries, so i want the message in three diffrent languages. So I cant use a parameters like that. Trying to post how i want but cant figure out how to post "code" in comments without format being messed up

Comment: You could of curse also use an if-statement like `if($Office -eq 'Office A') { $Office = "This is a longer dummy message"}`.

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted! :) I will see if i can figure that out, and then post results. Thanks for the help!!